# In GGTS, how do I have java classes reference jars from BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: eclipse, spring, grails, groovy

Using GGTS 3.6.0M1 with Grails 2.4, I have a java class file that needs an external jar to compile. That jar is defined in BuildConfig.groovy in the "compile" stage, but Eclipse still complains that the references class is not found (because it's not in the Java Build Path).

Since dependency management is performed by Grails, what's the best way to handle dependencies from Java classes that are within Grails projects?

EDIT: Refresh-dependencies doesn't solve the problem of my JAVA classes (under src/java) not seeing the jars in their classpath within Eclipse (showing project errors). If I compile externally - it works (grails compile).

Comment: I am not exactly sure where to find it in STS (since I have not used it for a long time) but look for `refresh-dependencies` option on the app in project explorer. That should update the dependencies. However, you would like to use GGTS if Grails is the framework.

Comment: Actually using GGTS. Edited. However, refresh-dependencies doesn't solve the problem of my JAVA classes (under src/java) not seeing the jars in their classpath. If I compile externally - it works (grails compile). However, within eclipse I get project errors.

Comment: I suppose grails compile can also be issued from the IDE AFAIK.

Comment: how about adding the jar file itself to the library folder or some other place visible for the java class in the project ...

Comment: But then I would have to manually add and re-add the jars (one by one) to the project, whereas MAVEN does all the dependency management for me.